# A question in proving the set of limit points of a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

[image]

This proof is from Charles C. Pugh - Real Mathematical Analysis P68. It uses $\lim\limits_{} S$ to denote the set of all limit points of $S$. It shows that $\lim\limits_{} S$ is closed.

It starts by considering $p$ is a limit point of $\lim\limits_{} S$. Then it argues that $p \in \lim\limits_{} S$ . By $p$ being a limit point of $\lim\limits_{} S$, it's clear that (in metric space) there exists a sequence $\left\{ p_{n} \right\}\subset \lim\limits_{} S$ such that $$\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{ n\to \infty} d(p_{n} , p) = 0
\end{align*}$$ Then since each $p_{n} \in \lim\limits_{} S$, it is the limit point of $S$ . There should exists a sequence $\left\{ p_{n,k} \right\}$ such that $$\begin{align*}
p_{n,k} \stackrel{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} p_{n}
\end{align*}$$ Then it directly said that since $p_{n,k} \to p_{n}$ , there exists a $q_{n}$ such that $$\begin{align*}
d(p_{n},q_{n}) < \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}$$I'm confused that how this $q_{n}$ exists, or how should I pick this $q_{n}$ from the sequence $\left\{ p_{n,k} \right\}$

I think the hard part is that $p_{n,k} \to p_{n}$ it means that $$\begin{align*}
\forall \epsilon> 0, \exists K(n) : \forall k > K \implies d(p_{n,k},p_{n})< \epsilon
\end{align*}$$ where I use $K(n)$ is that I think $K$ really depends on $n$ . As $n$ varies, this $K$ varies. For example, we have $$\begin{align*}
p_{1,1} , p_{1,2} , p_{1,3} , \cdots \to p_{1} 
\\ p_{2,1} , p_{2,2} , p_{2,3} , \cdots \to p_{2} \\ p_{3,1} , p_{3,2} , p_{3,3} , \cdots \to p_{3} 
\end{align*}$$ If I give $\epsilon = 1$ , in the first line, it may have for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ , $d(p_{1,k}, p_{1})< 1$ . However, for the second line, we have for all $k > 3$, we have $d(p_{2,k},p_{2})< 1$. Then for the third line, we have for all $k > 2$ , we have $d(p_{3,k},p_{3})< 1$ . Then how should pick the proper $q_{n}$ as stated in the book?

In fact, I attempted to "delete" some terms in the sequences. As the example above, given $\epsilon$, for the first line, there exists $K_{1}$ such that for all $k >K_{1} \implies d(p_{1,k},p_{1})< \epsilon$ . Then I delete all $p_{n,k}$ such that $k \leq K_{1}$ for all $n$. Then I check the second line. Then there should exists $K_{2}$ such that $k >K_{2} \implies d(p_{2,k},p_{2})< \epsilon$ . Then I delete all $p_{n,k}$ such that $k \leq K_{2}$ for all $n$ and so on.

However, the problem is that this is an "infinite deletion". That is, if I keep using this method, I will delete all $p_{n,k}$ such that $k \leq K_{1},k \leq K_{2},k \leq K_{3},\cdots$ for all $n$. It's like removing finite numbers infinitely times from a set containing infinite numbers, which I feel is an unsafe process.

Can you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: $K$ is allowed to vary with $n$—it doesn't matter. We don't need to fix a single $K$ such that $q_n = p_{n,K}$ for all $n$. We just need—for each $n$—some $K$, which may depend on $n$, such that $d(p_n,p_{n,K})<1/n$. And such a $K$ exists for any given $n$ because $(p_{n,k})$ converges to $p_n$.

Comment: **Your question:** If I give $\epsilon = 1$ , in the first line, it may have for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ , $d(p_{1,k}, p_{1})< 1$ . However, for the second line, we have for all $k > 3$, we have $d(p_{2,k},p_{2})< 1$. Then for the third line, we have for all $k > 2$ , we have $d(p_{3,k},p_{3})< 1$ . Then how should pick the proper $q_{n}$ as stated in the book? **Answer:** then you can pick $q_1=p_{1,k(1)}=1$, $q_2=p_{2,k(2)}=4$, and $q_3=p_{3,k(3)}=3$.